# Wrong sorting while using Query function

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, report, google-query-language

I've been trying to do a report about the quantity of breakdonws of products in our company. The problem is that the QUERY function is operating as normal, but the sorting order is well - a bit strange.
The data I'm trying to sort are as follows (quantities are blacked out since I cannot share those informations):
Raw data[image: 1]
First column - name of the product, second, it's EAN code, third, breakdown rate for last year, last column - average breakdown rate. "b/d" means "brak danych" or no data.
What I want to achieve is to get the end table with values sorted by average breakdown rate.
My query is as follows:

`=query(Robocze!A2:D;"select A where A is not null and NOT D contains 'b/d' order by D desc")`

Final result[image: 2]

As You can see, we have descending order, but there are strange artifacts - like the 33.33% after 4,00% and before 3,92%.
Why is that!?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x; SORT(x; INDEX(x;; 4)*1; 0))
 (QUERY(Robocze!A2:D; "where A is not null and NOT D contains 'b/d'"; 0));; 4)
```

Comment: It works flawlessly, but it outputs percentages, and I wanted model numbers. When I add select A then it breaks

Comment: Sorry but no. Data there is confidential. I don't know what happened, the query is as before but it works much better now